# tinymce Strikethrough when pasting from Word

Tags: tinymce

I'm using tinymce editor with the paste plugin. 
In some cases when I paste from a word document some of the words have a Strikethrough , even though there isn't one in the word docuemnt.

I saw [this question](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/forum/viewtopic.php?id=7610) , but it dosen't have an answer and I can't find any other similar questions.

How can I prevent the strikethrough while pasting?

Thank's In Advancce.

Answer (score 0):

You could do some paste handling of your own using [the paste parameter paste_preprocess](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/wiki.php/Plugin%3apaste).
For example could you remove some word formatings/styles of your own. The tinymce keep/remove-style-settings for the paste plugin do not seem to handle all cases.